# Typoscript - show CONTENT without header

Tags: typo3, typoscript, except

I have a contact popup which is displayed when the user clicks on a side button.
The layer should have a link at the bottom right corner and for this, I want to use the header_link field from tt_content. But I don't want to link the header also.

So, how can I get a CONTENT without header?

```
lib.contactLayer = COA
lib.contactLayer {
    10 = TEXT
    10.value = <a id="contactHandle" href="#"></a>

    20 = COA 
    20 {
        10 = CONTENT
        10 {
            table = tt_content
            select {
                pidInList = {$storageFolder.records}
                uidInList = {$record.contactLayer}
                orderBy = sorting
            }
        }

        20 = TEXT
        20.value = <a href="#" id="contactLayerClose"></a>

        30 = CONTENT
        30 {
            table = tt_content
            select {
                pidInList = {$storageFolder.records}
                uidInList = {$record.contactLayer}
                orderBy = sorting
            }

            renderObj = COA
            renderObj {
                10 = TEXT
                10 {
                    value = Kontakt aufnehmen
                    stdWrap.typolink {
                        parameter.field = header_link
                        wrap (
                            <span id="contactLayerLinkText">|</span>
                            <span class="icon"></span>
                        )
                        ATagBeforeWrap = 1
                        ATagParams = id="contactLayerLink" class="clearfix"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        wrap = <section id="contactLayer">|</section>
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** My approach was wrong from the beginning, because I was making 2 sql queries. This is the one I ended up with, using one CONTENT and renderObj:

```
lib.contactLayer = COA
lib.contactLayer {
    10 = TEXT
    10.value = <a id="contactHandle" href="#"></a>

    20 = COA 
    20 {
        10 = CONTENT
        10 {
            table = tt_content
            select {
                pidInList = {$storageFolder.records}
                uidInList = {$record.contactLayer}
                orderBy = sorting
            }

            renderObj = COA
            renderObj {

                10 = TEXT
                10.value = <a href="#" id="contactLayerClose"></a>

                20 = FILES
                20 {
                    references {
                        table = tt_content
                        uid.field = uid
                        fieldName = image
                    }
                    renderObj = IMAGE
                    renderObj {
                        file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
                    }
                }

                30 = COA
                30 {
                    10 = TEXT
                    10.field = header
                    10.wrap = <h1>|</h1>

                    20 = TEXT
                    20.field = subheader
                    20.wrap = <h2>|</h2>

                    30 = TEXT
                    30.field = bodytext

                    wrap = <div class="text">|</div>
                }

                40 = TEXT
                40 {
                    value = Kontakt aufnehmen
                    stdWrap.typolink {
                        parameter.field = header_link
                        wrap (
                            <span id="contactLayerLinkText">|</span>
                            <span class="icon"></span>
                        )
                        ATagBeforeWrap = 1
                        ATagParams = id="contactLayerLink" class="clearfix"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        wrap = <section id="contactLayer">|</section>
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd rather add your working version as answer and accept it as community wiki so this doesn't pop up anymore as unsolved question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach was wrong from the beginning, because I was making 2 sql queries. This is the one I ended up with, using one CONTENT and renderObj:

```
lib.contactLayer = COA
lib.contactLayer {
    10 = TEXT
    10.value = <a id="contactHandle" href="#"></a>

    20 = COA 
    20 {
        10 = CONTENT
        10 {
            table = tt_content
            select {
                pidInList = {$storageFolder.records}
                uidInList = {$record.contactLayer}
                orderBy = sorting
            }

            renderObj = COA
            renderObj {

                10 = TEXT
                10.value = <a href="#" id="contactLayerClose"></a>

                20 = FILES
                20 {
                    references {
                        table = tt_content
                        uid.field = uid
                        fieldName = image
                    }
                    renderObj = IMAGE
                    renderObj {
                        file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
                    }
                }

                30 = COA
                30 {
                    10 = TEXT
                    10.field = header
                    10.wrap = <h1>|</h1>

                    20 = TEXT
                    20.field = subheader
                    20.wrap = <h2>|</h2>

                    30 = TEXT
                    30.field = bodytext

                    wrap = <div class="text">|</div>
                }

                40 = TEXT
                40 {
                    value = Kontakt aufnehmen
                    stdWrap.typolink {
                        parameter.field = header_link
                        wrap (
                            <span id="contactLayerLinkText">|</span>
                            <span class="icon"></span>
                        )
                        ATagBeforeWrap = 1
                        ATagParams = id="contactLayerLink" class="clearfix"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        wrap = <section id="contactLayer">|</section>
    }
}
```